# How to use Laravel API Resources with additional queries?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-9

I have a database with the structure below;

```
(4677, 'Iceland', 'Torlakshofn', 63.8500000, -21.3666668, -9999.0),
(4678, 'Iceland', 'Stykkisholmur', 65.0666667, -22.7333336, 14.0),
(4679, 'Iceland', 'Olafsvik', 64.8833333, -23.7166672, 211.0),
(4680, 'Iceland', 'Eskifjordur', 65.0666667, -14.0166664, -9999.0),
(4681, 'Iceland', 'Vogar', 63.9666667, -22.3666668, 20.0),
(4757, 'India', 'Patna', 25.6000000, 85.1166687, 50.0),
(4758, 'India', 'Bhopal', 23.2666667, 77.4000015, 487.0),
(4759, 'India', 'Ludhiana', 30.9000000, 75.8499985, 243.0),
```

Which basically is a list of countries with their cities, but listed on one single table. Now, I would like to retrieve my resource collection like below;

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        country: 'Iceland',
        locations: [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "city": "City 1",
                "longitude": "69.1833344",
                "latitude": "34.5166667"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "city": "City 2",
                "longitude": "69.1833344",
                "latitude": "34.5166667"
            }
        ]
     },
     {
        id: 2,
        country: 'India',
        locations: [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "city": "City 1",
                "longitude": "69.1833344",
                "latitude": "34.5166667"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "city": "City 2",
                "longitude": "69.1833344",
                "latitude": "34.5166667"
            }
        ]
     }
]
```

I couldn't figure out how to retrieve such a response using Laravel API Resources. Could anybody help me out here?

Comment: And what ID would be the correct one for a country? For Iceland you have 5 records but you want to have just 1 id in the results...

Comment: @Luciano in my case, the ID is first record of the country. Although, I am just querying data by country name and therefore, you can ignore the ID.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have that result by using `Laravel API Resources`

I suggest using `groupBy('country')` to collect data of the same country.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah the natural response would be ```groupBy``` and than inside a foreach loop run another query to get the cities and attach to the response. However, I was thinking of whether there is a way to do it with API resources for reusibility and cleaner code.